# time handler which repeats itself n times in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

How to create a time handler which repeats itself n times in AndEngine

I'm using this but it only works once

```
private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler() {
    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;


    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(5, new ITimerCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                    initHardware();
                }
            });

    getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;

private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler() {

    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(5, true, new ITimerCallback() {

            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                counter++;
                initHardware();
                if(counter >= 5) {
                    mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
                }
            }
        });

    getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
}
```

Comment: This is correct: Note that the second parameter "true" sets the timerhandler to repeat infinitely. If set to false it only runs once.

Comment: but it is runs once then i changed     public TimerHandler(final float pTimerSeconds, final ITimerCallback pTimerCallback) {
  this(pTimerSeconds, true, pTimerCallback);
 }

Answer (score 0):

but it is runs once then i changed

TimerHandler.java lib file in 
org.andengine.engine.handler.timer

```
     public TimerHandler(final float pTimerSeconds, final ITimerCallback pTimerCallback) {
    this(pTimerSeconds, false, pTimerCallback);
}
```

to

```
 public TimerHandler(final float pTimerSeconds, final ITimerCallback pTimerCallback) {
    this(pTimerSeconds, true, pTimerCallback);
}
```

now its working infinitely

Answer (score 0):

```
TimerHandler abc;
 abc=new TimerHandler(1, true, new ITimerCallback() {
              int counter=0;
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                counter++;
                if(counter >= 60) {
                    mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(abc);
                    }
                elapsedText.setText("Seconds elapsed: " +counter);
                //fpsText.setText("FPS: " + fpsCounter.getFPS());
            }
        });
          getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(abc);
```

Comment: this contain the 60 seconds